# How to monitor total bandwith usage and get per process statistics?

Tags: networking

How can I monitor bandwith usage on my system? I would need accumulative statistics per process (not only live statistics).

Comment: Whoever manages site network should have a better tool available like `SolarWinds Orion` or `NetMRI`. Without knowing more about you setup, you should consult them.

Comment: I want to know each process use how many bandwidth

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: what does this mean ?  .... `but effect is not obvious`

Comment: probably relevant https://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/

Answer (score 0):

[`netatop`](https://www.atoptool.nl/netatop.php) module of `atop` contains support for per-process level networking accounting. You need to build the kernel module to use network accounting. Statistics can then be viewed using `atop`.